# Referencing element in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to know how to refer to elements in a loop in R. In STATA, it is done through `var' inside a loop.
I am working with loops and I want to refer to the variables inside each loop while regressing these variables on a list of variables (x1 x2 x3).
x1 variable also has suffixes so that the name can be split into several shorter parts.
The code I would make in STATA would be:

```
foreach credit in "short_term" "medium_term" "long_term" {
    foreach percentile in "p50" "p75" "p90" {
        foreach type in "high4" "high5" "high6" {
            reg y_-credit' x1_-percentile '_`type' x2 x3 
        }
    }
}
```

In R, if I create a list and make a loop, how do I refer to each element in the list? For instance:

```
credit <- c("short_term","medium_term","long_term") 
percentile <- c("p50","p75","p90") 
type <- c("high4","high5","high6") 

for (c in credit) {
    for (p in percentile) {
        for (t in type) {
            baseline_[c]_[p]_[t] <- lm(y_[c] — xl_[p]_[t] + x2 + x3)
        } 
     }
}
```

And then get a .txt file using sink to get all results (summary(baseline) for all baselines) together.

I hope my illustration was adequate in explaining my doubt. I am struggling with loops because of this (minor - when compared to STATA's `var') issue.

I await your response.

Thank you,
Pranav

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Also show, what you tried in R and where you got stuck.

Comment: Dear Kath, I am new to StackOverflow. I was unable to add the code properly and hence I uploaded an image. I shall try again to describe the code I tried on R (although the image shows what I wrote). Thank you, Pranav

Comment: Can you also share what kind of structures `baseline`,  `xl`, and `y` have? Have a look at [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) if you don't know how to share your data.

Comment: Dear Kath, I read the rules. I do not have access to the data (it is confidential). I apologize for the poorly framed question. Shall work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the `formula()` function to generate formulas from strings in R.

Since the OP isn't reproducible, we'll demonstrate `formula()` by using the `mtcars` data set:

```
data(mtcars) # Use motor trend cars data set
dvs <- c("mpg","qsec")
ivs <- c("am","wt","disp")
for(d in dvs){
     for(i in ivs){
          message(paste("d is: ", d, "i is: ",i))
          print(summary(lm(formula(paste(d,"~",i)),mtcars)))
     }
}
```

...and the first part of the output:

```
> for(d in dvs){
+      for(i in ivs){
+           message(paste("d is: ", d, "i is: ",i))
+           print(summary(lm(formula(paste(d,"~",i)),mtcars)))
+      }
+ }
d is:  mpg i is:  am

Call:
lm(formula = formula(paste(d, "~", i)), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.3923 -3.0923 -0.2974  3.2439  9.5077 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   17.147      1.125  15.247 1.13e-15 ***
am             7.245      1.764   4.106 0.000285 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.902 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3598,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3385 
F-statistic: 16.86 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 0.000285
```

Since the output from `lm()` can be saved in an object, one can also generate a `list()` of model objects, and manipulate them further in R.

To generate named variables for the `formula()` statement from vectors containing elements of the desired variable names, one can use the `paste()` or `paste0()` functions in a manner similar to the approach taken above with the `mtcars` data set. `paste0()` defaults to no spaces between arguments, where as `paste()` defaults to adding space between the arguments.

Again, making some guesses as to the actual intended formulae, we'll use the OP nested `for()` loops to generate strings that can be used with `formula()` in an `lm()` function.

```
# 
# generate formulas using content from OP
# 
credit <- c("short_term","medium_term","long_term") 
percentile <- c("p50","p75","p90") 
type <- c("high4","high5","high6") 

for (c in credit) {
     for (p in percentile) {
          for (t in type) {
               aFormula <- paste0("y_",c," ~ x1-",p,"_",t," + x2 + x3")
               print(aFormula)
          } 
     }
}
```

...and the start of the output:

```
> credit <- c("short_term","medium_term","long_term") 
> percentile <- c("p50","p75","p90") 
> type <- c("high4","high5","high6") 
> 
> for (c in credit) {
+      for (p in percentile) {
+           for (t in type) {
+                aFormula <- paste0("y_",c," ~ x1_",p,"_",t," + x2 + x3")
+                print(aFormula)
+           } 
+      }
+ }
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p50_high4 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p50_high5 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p50_high6 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p75_high4 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p75_high5 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p75_high6 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p90_high4 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p90_high5 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_short_term ~ x1_p90_high6 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_medium_term ~ x1_p50_high4 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_medium_term ~ x1_p50_high5 + x2 + x3"
[1] "y_medium_term ~ x1_p50_high6 + x2 + x3"
. 
. 
.
```

Note that the content in the OP inconsistently uses `-` vs. `_`, so I used `_` at all relevant spots in the formulae.

Comment: Thank you Len. This is exactly what I was searching for.